# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

### como va todo tengo un problema que no logro entender en el framework CodeIgniter con insertar en Oracle, tal vez ustedes me pueden ayudar, me sale este error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Filename: controllers/Administrativo.php

Line Number: 672

Backtrace:

### File: C:\xampp\htdocs\homologaciones\application\controllers\Administrativo.php
Line: 672
Function: _error_handler

Codigo del controllador administrador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui esta el codigo de la funciona de insertar a la base de datos Oracle
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código debe ir como texto, también debes indicar cual es la linea de código a la que hace referencia el error. Te recomiendo leer [answer] y tambien haz el [tour] para que mejore la calidad de tu pregunta y te puedan ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: Falta la parte de como se asigna la variable `$est_pensum`, debes agregarla para entender el problema? Al parecer esta obteniendo un `bool` y no un `array` como es esperado (esto puede pasar si la consulta no obtiene un registro)